# Bringing categories into table rows without using cursors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I got a table containing 3 columns:

```
NameColumn  CategoryColumn  QuantityColumn
Name1       Category1   5
Name2       Category1   8
Name3       Category1   10
Name4       Category2   3
Name5       Category2   15
Name6       Category2   7
```

I need to write a query to convert the above data into the following result set:

```
NameColumn  CategoryColumn  QuantityColumn
Category1   NULL        NULL
Name1       NULL        5
Name2       NULL        8
Name3       NULL        10
Category2   NULL        NULL
Name4       NULL        3
Name5       NULL        15
Name6       NULL        7
```

Is there anyway to do this without using cursors?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you putting `Category` values into the `NameColumn`? SQL is not a report-tool - do you presentation in a presentation layer.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Thank you. That's the right answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT NameColumn, CategoryColumn, QuantityColumn
FROM
(
    SELECT CategoryColumn AS NameColumn, NULL AS CategoryColumn, NULL AS QuantityColumn,
        CategoryColumn AS _cat, 1 AS _iscat
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY CategoryColumn
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NameColumn, NULL AS CategoryColumn, QuantityColumn, 
        CategoryColumn AS _cat, 0 AS _iscat
    FROM myTable
) x
ORDER BY _cat, _iscat DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cca43/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could, but unless you add metadata columns to the output, it will not be of much use.

```
  select NameColumn, CategoryColumn, QuantityColumn, 0 IsCategory
    from tbl
   union all
  select distinct CategoryColumn, CategoryColumn, null, 1
    from tbl
order by CategoryColumn, IsCategory desc, NameColumn;
```

Sure, to get your EXACT output order, you can omit and NULLify certain columns, e.g.

```
  select NameColumn, NULL as CategoryColumn, QuantityColumn
    from (
  select NameColumn, CategoryColumn, QuantityColumn, 0 IsCategory
    from tbl
   union all
  select distinct CategoryColumn, CategoryColumn, null, 1
    from tbl
         ) X
order by X.CategoryColumn, IsCategory desc, NameColumn;
```

But if you're intending to use the data outside of SQL Server, you'll want to keep the metadata to relate names and the categories to the original categories they came from. The IsCategory will also be useful to identify the headers that were picked out of the CategoryColumn.